# how to filter lines in log file containing particular string?

Tags: logstash

I gave log file as input through file plugin in input and output I need is lines containing particular string? So what I need to do in filter plugin to filter only those lines containing string for example "volume"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [conditional](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) application of the [drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html){} filter.

Comment: Yaeh Alain. But if it is field I can give if  [volume] { drop{} }    what to do for string?

Comment: From your example, "volume" is not your field; "volume" is your value.

Comment: Yaeh Its a value. How to check that?

Comment: How about using the conditionals?  Like:   if [path] =~ "error" { #regexp match }  or if [path] == "foo" { #exact match }

Comment: Here  path refers to?

Comment: I want the lines containing  string  "volume",  so  condition  i can use  is       if [  ]  == "volume"        what  that  [  ]  should contain?  You gave as path.

Comment: It's "field" and "value", so:  if [myField] == "myValue"  or [myField] =~ "myRegexp".

Comment: Yaeh Alain.If I Know the field I can give.But the string "volume" does not refer to any field.